# Setting up Unix for development dual boot with Vista and Windows Server 2008

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, emacs, development-environment, github

I'm a PC guy and a Microsoft Platform Developer. I've got a new assignment from my client whiche  has to be develop with open source technologies. Hhas already send me server information where I've to deploy. The hosting information he has given is CentOS environment with Ruby (with Rails) and Python support. I've chosen Ruby because I'm familiar with it.

I'm planning to setup a similar hosting environment on PC. I've a laptop (Sony Vaio) with Vista and Windows Server 2008. Is there any way I can install bootable CentOS keeping both Vista and Windows Server 2008? I don't want to use Virtual PC. I've checked a CentOS download section it confused me showing different version. Which one is suitable in my case? It is very important to keep Vista and Windows Server 2008. I can't compromise them over CentOS as I'm also working on a SharePoint project and Vista keeps my personal computing.

There are two more things to do after that. Emacs and Github. Client wants me to do all my development on Emacs and configure GiHub on it. Installation might not cause such problem but configuration probably difficult aspect for me on a Unix platform.

This all means a complete Open Source development environment need to be setup on/for a Microsoft Platform guy :)

Help!

Thanks.

Comment: which one is more useful and recommended for open source development?

Comment: What do you mean which one? Unix or Linux? I would say neither. It depends on for which platform you want to develop the opensource software. If you want to develop a Windows app neither is suitable. The most popular Unix would be Mac OS X, But there are also BSD, HP-UX, Solaris and AIX. All closed source by the way. There opensource versions like OpenBSD, FreeBSD or NetBSD. Linux is a UNIX like OS in is opensource. But you don't need to use opensource software to develop opensource software.

Answer (score 1):

> I've checked a CentOS download
>   section it confused me showing
>   different version. Which one is
>   suitable in my case?

I would suggest the same version your client's server is running with

> Is there any way I can install
>   bootable CentOS keeping both Vista and
>   Windows Server 2008?

CentOS will install grub as bootmanager, it should be able two boot both your windows installations, too. To make sure it work make a backup before you install CentOS.

> Client wants me to do all my
>   development on Emacs and configure
>   GiHub on it.

1. **Emacs:** I would not let any client tell me, which editor I have to use. What does the client care which editor I use to edit the files? The output of each editor is the same. So Take one you are comfortable with.
2. **GitHub:** http://help.github.com/ should help you to get started. If you have problems setting it up, you can come back here to ask for help.

> I don't want to use Virtual PC

Why? And do you mean the application "Virtual PC" or do you mean virtualization in general? Because I always prefer a virtual OS if I need another OS the my main OS for development, this way it can't destroy my system if something goes wrong, because it's running sandboxed. If you meant you don't like "Virtual PC" you can try [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) for free, [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (opensource) for free or [Parallels Desktop 4 for Windows](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/pd4wl/)

Comment: Agreed on the Emacs bit.  Bad juju.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi Versions of Ubuntu install nicely alongside Windows without partitioning etc. Should support most things you need.

http://wubi-installer.org/

Very easy to setup and pickup for a Windows user and give you a rich dev environment.

**ADDED:** 
I would use a Virtual box VM for the CentOS server stuff so you can go with a pure server version. I know you wanted not to use a VM but Unix deployments don't tend to be desktop OS's so it is probably the easiest way to get both the development enviroment you need and test deployment server.

Comment: He said "I'm planning to setup a similar hosting environment on PC" ubuntu is a linux too, but that is about almost everything that is similar between CentOS and Ubuntu (i.e. rpm vs apt)

Comment: Yep - missed out second bit of answer. Thanks for pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vmware.com - Hurry now, and download VMware Server - this will let you install many Unixes and Windows OSes on your desktop without having to do dual-boot or other such craziness.  Lowest impact to your development environment.

-Chris

Comment: Worth noting that it's a free download.